# The DataSet result is always empty in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dataset, sqlconnection, dataadapter

I am retrieving particular column value using DataSet.

This is my code:

```
public DataSet GetRedirectURL(string emailId)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Connection_String_Here"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("usp_Login", con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", emailId);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
        {
            SelectCommand = sqlComm
        };

        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

I have also used DataTable instead of it but the same result.
I have checked my Stored Procedure and when I pass Parameter it shows Data. So, nothing wrong with the SP. But the Table doesn't show any data and is always empty as shown below:

[image]

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your `SqlCommand` itself?

Comment: you didnt open your connection anywhere.  open it belore passing to command object

Comment: @VishalPawar even though opening the connection, the DataSet result is empty.

Comment: Follow this  It may help  https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Comment: Glad my answer helped you @noobprogrammer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to first evaluate the content of your `DataSet`. For instance, type in your Immediate Window (or add a quick watch) to check `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`. Basically, to assert your `DataSet` has been properly filled with the contents fetched from the database, and focus on the data assignment from the `DataSet` to the grid object you're using to display it.

Also, the *.Fill()* method has a returning object which is an int representing the amount of rows that have been successfully filled into the target object. For instance:

```
int result = da.Fill(ds);
```

Check the value of `result` after the *.Fill()* method has been executed.

Finally, I guess you're using a `DataGridView` object to visualize the results. If so, how are you binding data? Should be something like:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

PS: As I've read in other comments, no, you don't need to execute the *.Open()* method on the connection. That's not necesarry, it's done implicitely when using the *(using SqlConnection conn = SqlConnection..)*